# Obtain YouTube community posts behind paid channel subscription

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm subscribed to a YouTube channel where I would like to obtain the *community* posts from it.

Is that possible using YouTube API?

Comment: Note that I replaced the instances of the verb *to scrape* in your post above with the verb *to obtain*. In the context of YouTube (and YouTube APIs for that matter) *scraping* has a negative connotation since the [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) specs explicitly forbid scraping info out of YouTube's site. (See section  III.E.6 of that document.)

Comment: @stvar thank you. That's why i mentioned  `API` usage. so indeed i mean a legal thing. but thank you for correcting that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is negative: there's no YouTube Data API endpoint that'll provide the info you're looking for.

See the [official answers provided by Google staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%20community%20tab) on the company's own issue tracker site. For example, [this answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174382010#comment2) from Dec 1, 2020:

> *Status: **Won't Fix (Infeasible)***
>
> Unfortunately, this isn't possible at this moment. We don't have any API that return such data.

Comment: Thanks for that valuable answer. that's save time